# Outputting the differences of two array values from a dropdown menu with units converted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a project and am having trouble figuring this out.What I need to do is have two separate textboxes to input values, a dropdown menu of available units, and a dropdown menu of available foods. Based on the selections, I'd like to have a comparison calculation on the right side of the page that outputs the results. Here's the code I have so far:

```js
var stocks = [
  ["Beef (80/20) raw", "oz", 72, 4.85, 5.65, 0, 2.142, 19, 20, 1],
  ["Beef (90/10) raw", "oz", 50, 5.65, 2.83, 0, 1.109, 19, 18, 1],
  ["Milk", "fl oz", 10, 1.46, 0.45, 0, 1.944, 10, 13, 8],
  ["Soda", "fl oz", 10, 1.46, 0.45, 0, 1.944, 10, 13, 8],
  ["Bread", "slice", 50, 5.65, 2.83, 0, 1.109, 19, 18, 1],
  ["Flour", "cup", 50, 5.65, 2.83, 0, 1.109, 19, 18, 1]
]

function Stock (data) {
  return {
    name: data[0],
    servingUnit: data[1],
    calories: [data[2], ''],
    protein: [data[3], 'g'],
    fat: [data[4], 'g'],
    saturatedFat: [data[6], 'g'],
    sugar: [data[5], 'g'],
    sodium: [data[7], 'mg'],
    cholesterol: [data[8], 'mg'],
    unitsPerServing: data[data.length - 1]
  }
}

stocks = stocks.map(Stock)

var $selects = $('.selectStock')
var $quantity = $('#numberOfStocks')
var $comparisonResult = $('.comparison .result')

$selects.each(function() {
  $(this).append(stocks.map(function(stock, i) {
    return new Option(stock.name, i)
  }))
})

function format(data, multiplier, digits) {
  data = data.slice()
  data[0] = (+(data[0] * multiplier).toFixed(digits)).toLocaleString()
  return data.join(' ')
}

function stockFacts(stock, quantity) {
  return [
    format(stock.calories, quantity, 2) + ' calories<br>' +
    format(stock.protein, quantity, 2) + ' of protein<br>' +
    format(stock.fat, quantity, 3) + ' of fat<br>' +
    format(stock.saturatedFat, quantity, 2) + ' of saturated fat<br>' +
    format(stock.sugar, quantity, 2) + ' of sugar<br>' +
    format(stock.sodium, quantity, 2) + ' of sodium<br>' +
    format(stock.cholesterol, quantity, 2) + ' of cholesterol<br>'
  ]
}

$selects.add($quantity).on('input', updateAmount)

function getStock (select) {
  return stocks[+select.value]
}

function updateAmount() {
  var quantity = +$quantity.val() 
    
  $selects.each(function() {
    var $result = $(this).nextAll('.result').empty()
    var $amount = $(this).prev().find('.servingUnit').empty()
    var stock = getStock(this)
    if (!stock) return
    var amount = quantity * stock.unitsPerServing
    
    $amount.text(' (' + amount + ' ' + stock.servingUnit + ')')
    
    $result.html(stockFacts(stock, amount))
  })
  
  var selected = [].map.call($selects, getStock)
  $comparisonResult.empty()
  if (!selected[0] || !selected[1]) return
  var diff = {}
  Object.keys(selected[0]).forEach(function (k) {
    if (/^(name|servingUnit|unitsPerServing)$/.test(k)) return
    var first = selected[0][k].slice()
    var second = selected[1][k].slice()
    first[0] *= selected[0].unitsPerServing
    second[0] *= selected[1].unitsPerServing
    diff[k] = [Math.abs(first[0] - second[0]), first[1], first[0] > second[0] ? 'more' : 'less']
  })
  $comparisonResult.html(stockFacts(diff, quantity))
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=10px, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

  <label>
    Servings:
    <input type="number" id="numberOfStocks" value="1" min="0" />
  </label>

  <div>
    <div class="side">
      <h2>First Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
      <select class="selectStock">
        <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
      <h2>Second Item<span class="servingUnit"></span>:</h2>
      <select class="selectStock">
        <option value="-1">Pick a food!</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="comparison">
      <h2>Comparison:</h2>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="result"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Things to note are that I only have one textbox for both values, but I need to have once for each item (so 2). In terms of the drop down for units I need to have it so that only certain units are available for certain items (ie. if an item is measured in ounces it should have pounds, grams, kg and if it's in fl oz it should be in cups, gallons, liters). My current code also outputs the values for each item and then a comparison, but I need to only have the comparison data be outputted.

Thanks again for the help, it is much appreciated.

Comment: That is unclear... Your code (what is done) is working. Do you want someone to **ADD new functions** which are not there at all in your code ?

Comment: Yeah- pretty much. I'm not sure how to do it though?

Comment: First, do the calculations for euivalency between grams, pounds (etc.) and between cups, gallons (etc). Then add the dropdowns for all possibilities. Add the info about if it is solid or liquid in your product array. This wil be used to decide what is in the unit drop down. Then create the function to change the values based on the unit selected in the unit dropdown.... And good luck trying. (at least a try!)

Comment: Thanks! I'm having trouble but will do more research